# Qt - In QGraphicsScene how to find the transparent Item using itemAt?

Tags: c++, qt, logic

I am trying to get gif-Item using itemAt(gif->pos()). But I am getting the underlying background image.

From Qt-Help I came to know that itemAt() will give the topmost visible item. But my problem is My item is partially visible, so when I tried to acces it by giving it's end points it yielded the back ground imgae.

Can any body say how to get gif-item apart from over-riding/creting functions ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`items()`](http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/qgraphicsscene.html#items-3) and pass `Qt::IntersectsItemBoundingRect` as `ItemSelectionMode`. This will test if the point touches the bounding box without testing shape.

Comment: Well. Just so happened it's a bug in Qt. http://bugreports.qt.nokia.com/browse/QTBUG-19036 Before it's fixed, you will have to create a custom QGraphicsItem and override contains() to test for shape.